# How can I construct this URL for RetroFit API

Tags: android, retrofit

This is the URL I am using to query the results:

```
 http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22YHOO%22+and+startDate+%3D+%222015-11-10%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222016-11-10%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

I am using Retrofit for the first so far this is how I build the url:

```
   public static String getStockDataUrl(String stock_symbol){
        String startDate = Utils.getLastYear() ;
        String endDate = Utils.getTodayDate();
        try{
            String YAHOO_BASE_URL = Constants.YAHOO_BASE_QUERY;
            String QUERY_STOCK_DATA = Constants.QUERY_STOCK_DATA +
                    Constants.SYMBOL_QUERY +stock_symbol+ Constants.START_DATE_QUERY +startDate+"\" " +
                   Constants.END_DATE_QUERY + endDate+"\"";
            return YAHOO_BASE_URL + URLEncoder.encode(QUERY_STOCK_DATA, "UTF-8")
                    + Constants.FORMAT_QUERY
                    + Constants.TABLES_CALLBACK_QUERY;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

These are Constants used to create the URL

```
public static final String YAHOO_BASE_QUERY = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
    public static final String QUERY_STOCK_DATA = "select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where ";
    public static final String SYMBOL_QUERY = "symbol = \"";
    public static final String START_DATE_QUERY = "\" and startDate = \"";
    public static final String END_DATE_QUERY =  "and endDate = \"";
    public static final String FORMAT_QUERY = "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.";
    public static final String TABLES_CALLBACK_QUERY = "org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
```

I have to the stock_symbol input from the user and then create the url with last year date and todays date how can I achieve this with Retrofit API Interface ?

This is the method to query data with retrofit

```
public void getStockQuotes(String symbol) {
        QuotesAPI apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(QuotesAPI.class);

        String query = Utils.getStockDataUrl(symbol);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, query);

        Call<QuotesResponse> call = apiService.getQuotes(query);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<QuotesResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<QuotesResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<QuotesResponse> response) {
                List<Quotes> movies = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number of movies received: " + movies.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<QuotesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

This is the QuotesAPI interface I have created

```
@GET
        Call<QuotesResponse> getQuotes(@Url String url);
```

These are the LogCat details:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.android.stockhawk.quotes.QuotesResponse.getResults()' on a null object reference
                                                           at com.android.stockhawk.service.StockTaskService$1.onResponse(StockTaskService.java:175)
                                                           at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: paste your code and crash log

Comment: @grantonzhunag I have posted the crash log can you contact me on some IM  ?

Comment: @grantonzhunag I have added to code for retrofit

Comment: you can use debug to view the detail of the response instance in onResponse () method

Comment: @grantonzhunag thanks but I removed retrofit it was confusing for me. I moved on to gson. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface should be declared when using Retrofit.

```
public interface StockDataService {}
```

In this interface, declare a method:

```
// String int @GET annotation should be a subPath and you should declare a baseUrl
@GET("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql")
Call<Result> access(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

put string "q", "format", "diagnostics","env","callback" as keys of `options`
the actual values as values of `options`

Comment: I have to get the user input for String symbol

Comment: It worked but the problem is that it crashed on getting the List